Quantum Computing implementation
I am trying to implement a quantum algorithm written in an research paper. The layout is a linear layer , followed by an quantum activation function layer and then a layer of softmax. This is my current code of the model and layer implementation
`

import numpy as np
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble
    from qiskit_aer import Aer
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
    class QuantumActivationFunction(Layer):
        def __init__(self, num_features, output_size, **kwargs):
            super(QuantumActivationFunction, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.num_features =8
            self.output_size = 8
        
        def encode_data_to_qubits(self, data):
            # Implement the encoding of data to qubits
            num_samples, num_features = data.shape
            encoded_states = []

            for i in range(num_samples):
                x = data[i]
                qc = QuantumCircuit(num_features)
                for j in range(num_features):
                    angle_1 = np.arctan(x[j])
                    angle_2 = np.arctan(x[j] ** 2)
                    qc.h(j)
                    qc.ry(angle_1, j)
                    qc.rz(angle_2, j)
                encoded_states.append(qc)
            return encoded_states

        def entangle_qubits(self, qc):
            # Implement qubit entanglement
            num_qubits = qc.num_qubits
            for stride in range(1, num_qubits):
                for i in range(num_qubits):
                    control_qubit = qc.qubits[i]
                    target_qubit = qc.qubits[(i+stride)%8]
                    qc.cx(control_qubit, target_qubit)
            
        def compute_r(qc):
            r = [0] * 4
            for i in range(4):
                r[i] = qc.rz(np.pi,qc.qubits[i])
            return r
                
        # def build(self, input_shape):
        #     # Define any trainable parameters here
        #     self._input_shape = input_shape
        #     pass

        def call(self, data):
            # Implement the activation function logic here
            # For example, you can use the inputs to compute the quantum activation
            # return tf.nn.relu(inputs)  # Placeholder example, replace with your quantum activation function logi
            encoded_states = self.encode_data_to_qubits(data)
            for qc in encoded_states:
                self.entangle_qubits(qc)
                self.compute_r(qc)
            return encoded_states
                    

        # def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        #      #Return the shape of the output tensor
        #      return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)

    from keras.layers import Activation
    from keras.activations import softmax

    def baseline_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=374, activation='linear'))  # Linear layer
        model.add(QuantumActivationFunction(8,8))  # Quantum Activation Function layer
        model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))  # Output layer
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

The code is returning error :
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[105], line 1
----> 1 model = baseline_model()
      2 first_linear_layer_output = model.layers[0](X_train).numpy()
      4 print("Output of the first linear layer:", first_linear_layer_output)

Cell In[104], line 7
      5 model = Sequential()
      6 model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=374, activation='linear'))  # Linear layer
----> 7 model.add(QuantumActivationFunction(8,8))  # Quantum Activation Function layer
      8 model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))  # Output layer
      9 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py:205, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    203 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    204 try:
--> 205   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    206 finally:`your text`
    207   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback`

I have tried rechecking my code several times, I have even checked dimensions of my data but still the error persists. When I was running the functions of quantum layer separately , it was working fine but after integrating it into class , it showed again the same error.
Sincere request to everyone who can help

What's the research paper you are drawing this from?

Why are you applying the RZ gates? This isn't clear to me. Are you going to convert the QuantumCircuit objects to numerical data?
